# Call to 'abs' is ambiguous

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c++

This error is occuring specifically on this line

```
nRandom = abs(arc4random());
```

The full method is

```
void PlayLayer::update(float dt)
{
    if ( bPause || bBuy )
    {
        return;
    }
    nRandom = abs(arc4random());
    labNet->setVisible(false);
    labNetNum->setVisible(false);
    if ( mType == game_bet )
    {
        labNotice->setVisible(itemNotice->isVisible());
        labLeft->setOpacity(itemLeft->getOpacity());
        labCenter->setOpacity(itemCenter->getOpacity());
        labRight->setOpacity(itemRight->getOpacity());
        bStand = false;
        bDouble = false;
    }

    if ( mType == game_deal )
    {
        labNotice->setVisible(itemNotice->isVisible());
        labLeft->setOpacity(itemLeft->getOpacity());
        labCenter->setOpacity(itemCenter->getOpacity());
        labRight->setOpacity(itemRight->getOpacity());
        bStand = false;
    }

    if ( mType == game_play )
    {
        labNotice->setVisible(itemNotice->isVisible());
        labLeft->setOpacity(itemLeft->getOpacity());
        labCenter->setOpacity(itemCenter->getOpacity());
        labRight->setOpacity(itemRight->getOpacity());

//        if ( bStand && !bDouble)
//        {
//            this->createDealerCard();
//            this->addedDealCardEvalution();
//        }

    }

    if ( mType == game_end )
    {
        labNet->setVisible(true);
        labNetNum->setVisible(true);

        if ( mTPlay == play_lose )
        {
            labNetNum->setString(__String::createWithFormat("-$%d", nBet)->getCString());
        }
        if ( mTPlay == play_match )
        {
            labNetNum->setString("+0");
        }
        if ( mTPlay == play_win )
        {
            labNetNum->setString(__String::createWithFormat("+$%d", nBet)->getCString());
        }
        bNoticeClickEnable = false;
        labLeft->setString("");
        labLeft->setOpacity(120);
        labCenter->setString("SHUFFLE");
        labCenter->setOpacity(255);
        labRight->setString("PLAY");
        labRight->setOpacity(255);
        if ( g_nYourCoin > 200 )
        {
            nTempMaxBet = 200;
        }
        else
        {
            nTempMaxBet = g_nYourCoin;
        }
        bStand = false;



    }

    this->visibleItemCoins();
    this->drawScores();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for `arc4random()`:

```
uint32_t arc4random(void);
```

The signature for `abs()`:

```
int  abs(int) __pure2;
```

Then when I try what you have:

```
abs(arc4random());
```

XCode tells me this:

> Taking the absolute value of unsigned type 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned
>   int') has no effect

Which begs the question, why do you need the absolute value of an **un**signed integer?

Assuming you are not using negative numbers, you can then assign the random value directly to your variable. I would recommend casting it to something other than `uint32_t` if possible though. Without knowing what `nRandom` is, I cannot tell you what to cast it to though.

Comment: `int nRandom` is in PlayerLayer.h
Its to get a random set of playing cards, this also worked prior to XCODE 9 and iOS 11